# Ruby on Rails: Is there a way to instantiate relationships for already existing data instead of on creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Profile that has a one-to-one relation with the model Interest. On creation of a new Profile, I have

```
Interest.find_or_create_by(profile_id: @prof.id)
```

However, I had only recently defined this relation in my project, and such, older instances of Profile are not run through this find_or_create_by line. Is there a way to run this command (either through the shell or something) throughout my entire database, so that I may guarantee every instance of Profile is tied with an instance of Interest?

Comment: create a migration and just write ruby code that does it... ?

Comment: What would the command be?

Comment: @LeTran : How would you know for the previous `profiles` that which of them belonged to which `Interest` model records ?

Comment: Just an ordinary migration (have a read through the Rails Guide on migrations if you aren't familiar with creating one). Alternatively, just open up the rails console and do it by hand... but a migration means you can test it on your dev machine before deploying to any production data you have.

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala find_or_create_by does exactly that: it finds an existing interest instance tied with the given profile id, and if it doesn't find one it creates a new interest instance and ties it to that profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a migration and the following contents in it:

```
Profile.find_each do |profile|
  unless profile.interest.present?
    interest = profile.create_interest
  end
end
```

If you have large database then I will suggest go for a rake task as this migration will increase the deployment time when you will deploy this to production

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for. I will definitely reference this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one Interest instance (in my example id = 1) you can tie all the profiles to, then run console and:

```
Profile.all.each do |profile|
  if profile.interest_id.nil?
    profile.interest_id = 1
    profile.save
  end
end
```

Comment: That would tie all remaining profiles to the same interest instance. I need it to be unique interest instances

Comment: If there is no particular order you can apply then you have to do it one-by-one.